# how to create a custom dialog login button for facebook

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook

is it possible to create a custom dialog login button for facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create any button you want and in your tap callback use:

```
[loginDialog show];
```

where loginDialog is a FBLoginDialog.

If you want custom login *dialog*, the issue is much more complicated, see this question: [iPhone SDK / Facebook Connect: Using a custom login dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485771/iphone-sdk-facebook-connect-using-a-custom-login-dialog)